# What does `|> gpu` mean in Flux.jl

Tags: julia, flux.jl

As I was looking through a bunch of the Flux.jl tutorials here: https://fluxml.ai/tutorials.html many of them use the syntax `|> gpu` throughout the tutorials. I understand this has something to do with the GPU but what is this special syntax doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you are seeing used here is not specific to Flux.jl but rather a general Julia syntax which simple wraps the statement on the left of the `|>` in whatever function is on the right. So in this case, it is equivalent do just doing `gpu(some_statement)` where the `some_statement` represent the code on the left of the `|>`.

Read more about this paradigm (Function piping and composition) in the Julia docs: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#Function-composition-and-piping